# Using Custom JSON Deserialization in Jackson

Tags: json, jackson, json-deserialization

I am trying to create objects of a complex class with the Jackson library. Each object has a schema that the deserializer needs to use to interpret the JSON. My question is how to supply the schema to the deserializer?

The deserializer extends the class JSONDeserializer, which has a no-argument constructor and an abstract method deserialize(parser,context) that must be overridden. I would like to use instead the alternate method deserialize(parser,context, value) where value is the partially constructed object, which includes the schema. That is, the deserialize method could call value.schema() to access the schema. The object itself is constructed piecewise with a builder, which the alternate method uses.

I have found no documentation on how to register the alternate deserialize method with the object mapper to insure that it, rather than the overridden abstract method, is called.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So Lets say you have a class called `User` which has a which has a property called `Data` which has date field `birthdate`, and you don't want to use the standard Date deserializer and wants to use your custom one. below is how it can be achieved.

> User.java

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class User {

    @JsonProperty("code")
    public Integer code;
    @JsonProperty("status")
    public String status;
    @JsonProperty("message")
    public String message;
    @JsonProperty("time")
    public String time;
    @JsonProperty("data")
    public Data data;

}
```

> Data.java

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Data {

    @JsonProperty("id_hash")
    public Integer idHash;
    @JsonProperty("user_name")
    public String userName;
    @JsonProperty("user_surname")
    public String userSurname;
    @JsonProperty("birthdate")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = BirthdayDeserializer.class)
    public Date birthdate;
    @JsonProperty("height")
    public Integer height;
    @JsonProperty("weight")
    public Integer weight;
    @JsonProperty("sex")
    public Integer sex;
    @JsonProperty("photo_path")
    public String photoPath;

}
```

> BirthdayDeserializer.java

```
public class BirthdayDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date> {
    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jsonparser, DeserializationContext deserializationcontext) throws IOException {

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String date = jsonparser.getText();
        try {
            return format.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

> Main.java to test it.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String json = "{\n" +
                "    \"code\": 1012,\n" +
                "    \"status\": \"sucess\",\n" +
                "    \"message\": \"Datos Del Usuario\",\n" +
                "    \"time\": \"28-10-2015 10:42:04\",\n" +
                "    \"data\": {\n" +
                "        \"id_hash\": 977417640,\n" +
                "        \"user_name\": \"Daniel\",\n" +
                "        \"user_surname\": \"Hdz Iglesias\",\n" +
                "        \"birthdate\": \"1990-02-07\",\n" +
                "        \"height\": 190,\n" +
                "        \"weight\": 80,\n" +
                "        \"sex\": 2\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addDeserializer(Date.class, new BirthdayDeserializer());
        mapper.registerModule(module);
        User readValue = mapper.readValue(json, User.class);
        System.out.println(readValue);
    }
}
```

Check the main method as how I have registered the custom `Deserializer`.

Comment: Not exactly what I asked. In your example, suppose that instead of using new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), I want the date format to be a parameter, such as new SimpleDateFormat(myDateFormat). How would I pass the parameter myDateFormat to the deserializer?

Comment: Is your schema going to change? if not then Can't we do it the way it has done for the date above? I mean hard code it or read it from some file ?

Comment: No, the schema will depend on the the situation. It's like a database table. The user will define the schema as part of configuring the code. The schema will be held in a field in the object.

Comment: OK. check if the 6th solution from here http://programmerbruce.blogspot.in/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think this is what I need. The 6th solution seems to apply when you want to create objects that are all subclasses of a single parent and where the JSON indicates which subclass is to be used. In my case, all the objects are a single class, but each object has its own schema. The schema is specified externally to the JSON, and while the caller knows which schema applies, the JSON does not include such an indicator. Rather, the schema is supplied by the caller.

Comment: Again, my question is how to use the alternate method deserialize(parser,context, value) of the Class JsonDeserializer specified in the Javadoc.